# When are Heavenly decrees made?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year

Since Hashem is not restricted by time, when are the heavenly decrees made?
From the beginning of time?
Every Rosh Hashanah?
In real-time, i.e. whenever necessary?

Comment: וַיֹּ֤אמֶר פַּרְעֹה֙ אֶל־יוֹסֵ֔ף אַחֲרֵ֨י הוֹדִ֧יעַ אֱלֹהִ֛ים אוֹתְךָ֖ אֶת־כׇּל־זֹ֑את אֵין־נָב֥וֹן וְחָכָ֖ם כָּמֽוֹךָ Apparently God told Yosef before Paroh said that, even though God is "above time".

Comment: Interesting point @DoubleAA

Comment: Since Hashem is not restricted by time, maybe it is all one thing from His perspective so there is no real difference?

Answer (score 0):

ראש השנה ט"ז תניא הכל נידונים בר"ה וגזר דין שלהם נחתם ביוה"כ דברי ר"מ ר' יהודה אומר הכל נידונין בר"ה וגזר דין שלהם נחתם כל אחד ואחד בזמנו בפסח על התבואה בעצרת על פירות האילן בחג נידונין על המים ואדם נידון בר"ה וגזר דין שלו נחתם ביוה"כ.
ר' יוסי אומר אדם נידון בכל יום שנאמר {איוב ז':י"ח} ותפקדנו לבקרים רבי נתן אומר אדם נידון בכל שעה שנא' {איוב ז':י"ח} לרגעים תבחננו.

Answer (score -2):

צדיק גוזר ה' מקיים
The Tzaddik decrees, haShem performs it (Chazal).

When the Tzaddik of the era decrees, that's when H' decrees. Mainly on Rosh Hashanah. That's why Rabbi Nachman was so adamant his followers all gather at him for R"H. The combination of space-time with the root soul the Tzaddik Chai Almin.

Refs: Sifrei Breslev and Na Nach

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question was about decrees made by heaven, not decrees made by Tzaddikim. Hashem doesn't only decree if tzaddikim decree!

Comment: @ElonMusk What's your understanding of צדיק גוזר ה' מקיים?

Comment: Whatever my understanding of it is, it still doesn't answer @Shababnik's question. It has nothing to do with it.