# What does it mean that judgement happens on Rosh Hashanah?

Tags: time, rosh-hashanah-new-year

What does it mean that G-d judges people on Rosh Hashanah, if G-d is 'outside of time'?

It's one thing to say that G-d performs an action (e.g. sends the Maan, talks to a prophet) that has a particular time of occurrence as observed in our physical world. But the act of judging itself is not an action observable in the world (though the results of judgement are), but more something that's occurring in the spiritual realms, so how can it have a specific timestamp and be "happening *on*" Rosh Hashanah?

Could it be said that "G-d judges on Rosh Hashanah" is also referring to something that has a timestamp in this world - such as referring to the notion that the judgement depends on (i.e. is a function of) the state of the person (their merits, etc.) *as of the time* of Rosh Hashanah (+Ten days of Teshuva)?

Comment: Dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/136811/33217

Comment: It’s similar but not exact dupe. That question asks when the decrees are made, but this question says outside of time means it doesn’t even make sense to ask ‘when’

Comment: G-d Himself is not bound by time, but the spiritual worlds are. See Ramchal Derech Hashem part 4 in regards to the Moadim.